# Python 2.7, np.asarray, TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a .txt file with 390 rows and some 8000 columns. The data consist of only 1s and 0s separated by a white space. I want to count the number of times the number 1 appears in each column (total sum per column) for all columns. I am using numpy arrays for this. The problem is I keep getting the following error message in the script line "b = a.sum(axis=0)":

"TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

Any suggestion would be welcome !

This is the simple code I am using:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('test1.txt', dtype='S', delimiter=',') 
a = np.asarray(my_data)

import sys  
sys.stdout = open("test1.csv", "w") 

b = a.sum(axis=0)
print b
```

An input example, test1.txt:

```
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
```

Expected output:

```
2 2 2 0 3 3 2 3
```

Comment: The first step is to use `genfromtxt` correctly.  Did you print `a` or look at its properties?  Or look at `my_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you are importing data with dtype='S' that is a string. You have to import data with the proper `dtype`, like `int`.

You don't need to import `csv` and you don't need to use `np.asarray`. Just open file with `np.genfromtxt` with `delimiter=' '` and `dtype=int`.

Try:

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt('test1.txt', dtype=int, delimiter=' ')
b = my_data.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Excellent !!. Thanks so much @Francesco Nazzaro !